# Modifying / Resetting the Last reboot time

Tags: windows-xp, windows-xp-embedded

I am trying to recreate a problem I encountered to try to confirm the root causes of it. One of the possible theory is that the problem is being caused because the server hadn't restarted for along time. Since I've already restarted the computer, Is there a way of resetting/modifying the "Last Reboot time" so the computer thinks it hasn't restarted for along time?
I am using

`systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"`

The computer is running Windows XP Embedded if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answer is *no*, you cannot do that.

Problems whose root-cause is related to the time passed since the last reboot are not unusual. But there is not just one reason why such problems happen, and consequently there is not one single setting you can change to reproduce the problem.

An operating system has a number of counters that will increase while the system is running. Some are directly proportional to the time gone by, others are driver by other events.

Even if you managed to change one value to make it look as if the system had been running for a long time, the problem may be related to another value, which you did not change.

Such counters may reset due to certain conditions. Many will start from zero after a reboot, but they may also start over from zero for other reasons. Another reason for a counter to start over from zero would be if it reaches a maximum value. There can be bugs which will cause problems when such a counter overflows.

But to debug the problem you need to know a bit more about what is triggering it than just "because the server hadn't restarted for a long time"